# How to load repeater on div scroll down instead of browser window scroll down?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I have a repeater whose records load on scrolling down main browser window but i want to add a scrollable div and load repeater on scrolling down that div instead of the main browser window. 
This is what i have right now..

http://snag.gy/MKKFn.jpg  (this one is working just fine, i am able to load repeater records on browser window scroll down).

This is what i want to achieve..
http://snag.gy/n9Ufw.jpg  (i have added scrollable div and now i do not know how to load repeater on scrolling this div instead of browser window).

ASPX:

```
<div id="scr" style="height:400px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y: scroll;>
    <div id="dvCustomers" >    
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptCustomers" runat="server" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;
                border: dashed 0px #04AFEF; background-color:#00BFFF">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><u><span class="name">
                            <%# Eval("MsgId") %></span></u></b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>City: </b><span class="city"><%# Eval("FromId") %></span>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                        <b>Postal Code: </b><span class="postal"><%# Eval("ToId") %></span>
                        <b>Country: </b><span class="country"><%# Eval("Msg")%></span>                                          
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
      </div>
 </div>
```

code to load repeater:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageIndex = 1;
    var pageCount;



    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            GetRecords();
        }
    });
//GetRecords() is for loading records in repeater
```

**UPDATE**
I tried ....

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271466/2064292

And it worked! But strangely it loads records just once and then stops working. For example if there are 22 records then on scrolling down 10-20 records get loaded but after that it stops functioning.

It did not work.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662528/load-ajax-when-scroll-reaches-80>

There is also an example!

Comment: @SebastianWiteczek I dont think that would work, because i do not want to load on scrolling main window itself. I want to load on scrolling div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked..https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271466/2064292
But i it was working just once i.e records were loading just once on scrolling down and then stopped working so i changed `#flux{width:400px;height:400px;overflow:auto;}` in that answer to inline

`style="width:400px;height:400px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow:-y:scroll;`

It solved everything.