# Zend paginator get all items per page using setItemCountPerPage() function

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination

I am using SE4 application of Zend framework. After executing query with Paginator, I am setting items per page like 10, 20, 50, all etc. using function `setItemCountPerPage()` of zend.

It is working fine for number provided or for zero value. But I have thousands of records and want to show all on single page without pagination.

I am using following code after query-

```
$this->view->paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($select);
$this->view->paginator->setItemCountPerPage($perPage, 10);
$this->view->paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page',1));
```

Please let me know what value should I provide for $perPage, so all items fetched by query will get display on page.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the size of your list (http://php.net/manual/de/function.sizeof.php), or deactivate the pagination. But if you have thousands of records, it would be a good idea to load them in sequence, not all at once :) Probably with ajax on scroll to bottom of page ([Load ajax when scroll reaches 80%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662528/load-ajax-when-scroll-reaches-80)).