# How to get infinite scroll until all results are displayed in Elasticsearch JS API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, elasticsearch, pagination, infinite-scroll

I am developing UI for a search engine using React. For Searching, I am using Elasticsearch. I am able to connect and fetch results from my index, but I'm only able to fetch only those number of results of which size i specified. I want to enable Infinite scroll until the client reaches to the end of results.

I need help in implementing scan & scroll and pagination

Here is my code of **app.js** component

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './header';
import Footer from './footer';
import SearchResults from './searchresults';
import elasticsearch from 'elasticsearch';

let client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace'
})


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { results: [], search_query: '*' }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    } 

handleChange ( event ) {
    var search_query = event.target.value;
    var size = 20;

    client.search({
        index: 'photos',
        type: 'photo',
        q: search_query,
        size: size

    }).then(function ( body ) {
        this.setState({ results: body.hits.hits })
    }.bind(this), function ( error ) {
        console.trace( error.message );
    });
}

render () {
    return (
        <div className="main">
            <Header />
            <div className="row test">
                <div className="col-xs-4"></div>
                <div className="col-xs-4">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12">            
                                <input id="search" className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Start Searching" name="search" onChange={ this.handleChange }></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xs-4"></div>
                <br />
                </div>
                <div className="test bclass">
                    <SearchResults results={ this.state.results } />
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-default">Load More</button>
                </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default App;
```

And here is my code for **searchresults.js** component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import LazyLoad from 'react-lazy-load';

let i = 1;


class SearchResults extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { results: [] }
} 

render () {
    return (
        <div className="search_results">
            <hr />
            <ul>
            { this.props.results.map((result) => {
                return (
                            <li key={ result._id + i++}>
                                <LazyLoad className="lazy">
                                    <img className="image" src={result._source.file_name} alt="Search Result" />
                                </LazyLoad>
                            </li>
                        ) }) }      
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
}

SearchResults.propTypes = {
    results: PropTypes.array
}

export default SearchResults;
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I guess i have written everything above. Let me know where you got confused?

Comment: @hering I think, How to implement pagination??

Comment: @RohitMotwani Is there a reason you use the `let` keyword for `client`? Or `let i = 1;`? `let` is a block scope keyword. It is declared outside of your export object.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of AJAX call on scroll as in Facebook home page; use a global incrementing `counterVariable` that increments on each AJAX call for your ElasticSearch with parameters `from` records of your result documents of `size` you want in one AJAX call of scroll. Do increment on every ajax call.

For javaScript of calling AJAX on scroll refer [Similar Solved Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10662576/7081346) .

Comment: Thanks, for letting me know that. I'm confused on how to implement it in my code.